# write a file multiple times

Tags: ruby, file, download

I would like to know how to write a picture twice without writing it once and then copying it.
When a picture is downloaded, it is written in the /tmp and then copied to the wanted path ( I think ) meaning that the following code :

```
cover_buffer = download_pic(link)      
buffer2 = cover_buffer
open(@dir + 'cover.jpg', 'wb') do |pic|
    pic << cover_buffer.read()
end
open(@dir + 'cover2.jpg', 'wb') do |pic|
    pic << cover_buffer2.read()
end
```

does not work since the both cover_buffer and buffer2 both point to the same file whitch was moved when writing cover.jpg
Executing that code will correctly write the picture in cover.jpg but cover2.jpg will be an empty file

Comment: What class is `cover_buffer`?

Comment: What does `download_pic(link)` return? Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TESTED SOLUTION**

In file `two_for_one.rb`:

```
current_dir  = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
new_file_1   = File.new(File.join(current_dir, 'image_1.png'), 'w')
new_file_2   = File.new(File.join(current_dir, 'image_2.png'), 'w')
origin_file  = File.join(current_dir, 'original_image.png')

begin
  File.open(origin_file, "r") do |source|
    until source.eof?
      chunk = source.read(1024)
      new_file_1.write(chunk)
      new_file_2.write(chunk)
    end
  end
ensure
  new_file_1.close()
  new_file_2.close()
end
```

Command line:

```
$ ruby two_for_one.rb
```